# Thread sleep in a for loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I need your help for using this method:

```
for (int i =0; i<dt.count; i++)
{
    process...
    sleep(3000);
}

int sleeptime=0;
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i &#60; mylist.Items.Count;)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(mylist.Items[i].Name.ToString() + "starting...");
        sleeptime = int.Parse(mylist.Items[i++].TimeSpan.ToString()) - timer2.Interval;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleeptime);
    }
    timer1.Start();
    timer2.Stop();
}
```

But I don't see my data flow like waterfall.

Comment: can you edit your question? it's not clear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 13):

You are blocking the UI thread - no updates will usually show until you leave the event-handler. A hacky approach is to use `Application.DoEvents()`, but this is lazy and risks re-entrancy *especially* if you are pausing.

A better approach is to do the work on a background thread, and use `Invoke` to push the data to the UI (don't talk to the UI from the worker thread).

Or just add individual items in separate ticks?

Here's an example using `BackgroundWorker` for the work, using `ReportProgress` to push items onto the UI:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // setup some form state
        Form form = new Form();
        ListView list = new ListView();
        list.View = View.List;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        form.Controls.Add(list);
        list.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        // start the worker when the form loads
        form.Load += delegate {
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        };
        worker.DoWork += delegate
        {
            // this code happens on a background thread, so doesn't
            // block the UI while running - but shouldn't talk
            // directly to any controls
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++) {
                worker.ReportProgress(0, "Item " + i);
                Thread.Sleep(150);
            }
        };
        worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object sender,
           ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            // this is invoked on the UI thread when we
            // call "ReportProgress" - allowing us to talk
            // to controls; we've passed the new info in
            // args.UserState
            list.Items.Add((string)args.UserState);
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use instead System.Threading.Timer class. The timer's callback is executed on a thread from ThreadPool, not the UI thread. But than, you can't directly access any GUI controls, so you would have to use Invoke.